# When a link is clicked it should pop up - Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, blogger

I need a javascript code that will pop when a particular link is clicked on. Please help me with the right code please i am using blogger

Comment: You need to follow this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Comment: What do you mean "Pop Up"? as in open a new window or open in a popup window inside the same window?

Comment: @JKirchartz Open a pop up window inside the same window

Comment: @Davidrexng what you're looking for is a Modal window - there's a lot of Javascript plugins that offer something like this. One of the first ones to pop up when I searched was this: https://github.com/benceg/vanilla-modal - you can load it into your site from a CDN like this one: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vanilla-modal then follow the examples on the github link.